# C# Replacing strings in Word Document, but without formatting

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

I'm having a little trouble with this method. It's function is to find a string in the Word document and replace it with another string.

```
public virtual void FillDocumentByText(Dictionary<string, string> parameterList, Word.Document doc)
    {            
        foreach (string key in parameterList.Keys)
        {
            Word.Find findObject = doc.Application.Selection.Find;
            findObject.ClearFormatting();
            findObject.Text = key;
            findObject.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
            findObject.Replacement.Text = parameterList[key];

            object replaceAll = Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
            findObject.Execute(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                ref replaceAll, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
        }
    }
```

The problem is: When I use this method, it works, but they make the first letter uppercased regardless of the string that I passed, and it can't be like that, example:

```
parameterList.Add("key1", "strange uh?");
```

And the final output in the document becomes "Strange uh?", even if the string that is supposed to be replaced is in the middle of the sentence.

Comment: A bit off-topic, but: if you use .NET 4/C# 4, you should be able to drop all those `ref oMissing` parameters and use named parameters to specify the one(s) you need to (this was just the sort of reason why optional and named parameters were added).

Comment: @TimS. Those oMissing's was the first thing I tried and it worked, so I never locked back... I'm using .NET 4.5 by the way. I don't consider myself a "good" programmer yet, so just a quick question, I'm using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, how could I avoid using those oMissing's? All the examples I've found on the internet used those...

Comment: [Looks like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.find.execute(v=office.14).aspx) it should be `findObject.Execute(Replace: ref replaceAll);`